# How to adjust my data into a curvier graphic

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to know how to make this graphic:[image: original].
Into this graphic:[image: Second graphic] by making the software "predict" the curve and adjust so that it's not linear between two points.

Comment: Try a low pass filter -- it will smooth out the sharp edges.

Comment: Please post your code ,not the pictures.

Comment: If you are using ListPlot, have you tried a higher InterpolationOrder?

Comment: Sorry, didn't think about posting my code, will do that next time! InterpolationOrder worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = {
  {0.`, 1.`}, 
  {3.8317059702075125`, -0.40275939570255287`}, 
  {7.015586669815619`, 0.30011575252613093`},    
  {10.173468135062722`, -0.2497048770578432`},
  {13.323691936314223`, 0.21835940724787295`}, 
  {16.470630050877634`, -0.19646537146865714`},
  {19.615858510468243`,  0.1800633753443156`}, 
  {22.760084380592772`, -0.16718460047381806`},
  {25.903672087618382`,  0.15672498625285222`}, 
  {29.046828534916855`, -0.14801110997277753`},
  {32.189679910974405`,  0.14060579818398222`}, 
  {35.33230755008387`, -0.13421124031000067`}, 
  {38.474766234771614`, 0.12861662207206997`}, 
  {41.61709421281445`, -0.12366796076983713`},
  {44.75931899765282`, 0.11924981201068946`}, 
  {47.90146088718545`, -0.11527369412016794`}};
```

Use the option [`InterpolationOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html). The default is `None`

```
Options[ListPlot, InterpolationOrder]

(* {InterpolationOrder -> None} *)

ListPlot[
 data,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> Dashed,
 InterpolationOrder -> 2,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: plot with a curvier interpolated joining line]

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!